# Throw Declarations

Tags: c++, exception, throw

The following code makes no sense.

```
void c() throw (XA) {
    throw XB();
    throw XA();
}
```

I specify to function c that it should throw an XA class but it still throws an XB and that XB is caught in the main. What is the point of that "throw (XA)" next to the function declaration?

Comment: Are you using MSVC, by any chance? It never implemented exception specifications per the standard. It ignores all expeption specifications except `throw()` (an empty one), and gives the latter a non-standard meaning (one similar to C++11's `noexcept`). What is supposed to happen is that `throw XB()` would lead to a call to `unexpected()`, and eventually `terminate()` and `abort()`.

Comment: See a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec).

Comment: Rationale for not using exception specifications: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Answer (score 0):

The goal of below declaration is not *ignoring* any exception other than `XA`.

```
void c() throw (XA)
```

It will throw `XA` exceptions (or its derived types) and invokes `std::unexpected` for other exceptions.

> If this function throws an exception of some type other than X, the
>   function calls std::unexpected instead of looking for a handler or
>   calling std::terminate.

For more information [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) this and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec). Moreover, using exception specifications in function declarations are deprecated.

So, your code will call `std::unexpected` or `std::terminate` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note; The `throw()` clause has been deprecated in favor of the `noexcept` clause.

In the situations where you declared a `throw()` declaration, over time (real code) would slowly add more and more scope until it was not worth it or you never threw anything.

So it was decided to just support these extremes (and thus the new definition).